# Determine the value of Vx if the power dissipated by resistor Rx is 450W and Rx=50 Ohms

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: The problem]

I keep getting figures that are out of these ranges. Maybe I am doing it wrong. So far I've been adding the possible voltages with 200V to get a total voltage, then using Ohms's Law to see if any of the voltages squared divided by 50 ohms would equal 450W. I also tried finding the equivalent resistance and working from there, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try calculating the current flowing through resistor Rx (hint - P = I^2 R - and then using this current to find the 1) voltage dropped on the 10ohm  resistor below it, and also the voltage dropped on Rx.   Then use kirchoffs voltage law to find the missing Vx.